# Why tableview cell text not changed according to orientation, while cell height did

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiinterfaceorientation, landscape-portrait

my code as below,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Color Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];    
    ......
    ......
    ......

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:14.0f];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:24.0f];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat rowHeight;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
        rowHeight = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 52) / [colorArray count];
    } else {
        rowHeight = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 64) / [colorArray count];
    }
    return rowHeight;
}
```

When running it, table view could auto reorientate correctly, cell height as well. But cell text size does not change accordingly.

Why? How to fix it?

left is on portrait, right is on landscape

[image: left is on portrait, right is on landscape]

Comment: it seems font size is reduced. i think ratio of cell height and font size is not correct in landscape mode . just reduce the font size further more .

Comment: no, the text sizes in portrait and landscape are exactly same, not changed according to orientation. Only cell height did. I added a snapshot of comparison.

Comment: Do you have a minimum font size set in the IB?

Comment: tried it, even set minimum size (9 pt) samler than the size (14) set in the code. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` not reload when change orientations in device,reload your table view after changing orientation

Comment: do you mean `self.tableView reloadData` ? Where to put it ?

Comment: add self.tableView reloadData when change orientation.

Comment: add it in `viewDidLoad` or `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, or other?

Comment: -(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if(port right)
    {
        //reload action;
    }
    else
    {
        //reload action;
    }
    
}